# programmatically disable incoming SMS messages to a Twilio number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have a Twilio number that can receive SMS messages. Unlike calls, it isn't possible to reject an SMS and accordingly, I get charged even if I don't want the message. Let's say someone bombs my account with spam messages. I want to be able to detect this and disable receiving SMS messages for my Twilio number with the REST API. I know I can login to Twilio and disable messages but I want to be able to do it programmatically. How can this be accomplished in Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can [disable receiving SMS messages on your Twilio number by removing the webhook URL from the number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181648-Is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-SMS-on-my-Twilio-phone-number-). You can do this via the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest), using the [incoming phone numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers). Use the API to update the number and remove the URL.

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
# check out the list resource examples on this page
@number = @client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.get("PHONE_NUMBER_SID")
@number.update(:sms_url => "")
```

Let me know if that helps at all.